# is it feasible to make chess application in 2 months?

Tags: game-design

We are final year B.tech students wanted to just ask that if we work 2 months on making chess application,will it suffice ?

Wanted to know if it is feasible given -

```
   1.Logic implementation is not a problem (will use AI)
   2.We are C++ programmers.
   3.We want to make 2D GUI, didn't selected any language for this purpose and we 
     need to learn just that part of the language which will help in making GUI for the application.
```

Comment: -1, a really localized question and heavily dependent on the team makeup

Comment: you really need to say if you want to do AI or not.

Comment: Closing because it's too localized, and not specific enough.  Basically asking "How do I make game X", which is off topic. http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-to-make-an-entire-game-x-off-topic

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question deserving of a well-meaning response.  My response is that, yes it is totally feasible.  I personally made a 2-player (no AI) version of chess as a school project in Java in a month or so, as one person.  More people would do it faster/better.  Though getting a smart AI is the difficult part really, so it kind of depends how "good" you need the AI to be.  Either way, it's definitely feasible to get some form of a chess game done in that time.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know how this project turned out. Had I been here when this question was asked, I would've recommended against creating a GUI, as there are several free ones available. Or, if they still insisted on creating a GUI, it should've been one that communicates with the chess engine using the UCI or the XBoard protocol.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely.

The main factors of the development time I would say is:

- How skilled you are as programmers - **Edit: this may be the biggest problem for you if you aren't experienced with your programming language of choice.** I'm stressing this here because I did not realise that you were saying you didn't have much experience in the language you are going to use. If that's the case I'd consider the project high risk.
- How you decide to display the game
  (console, GUI, 3D?)
- How good you are
  at communicating and working together
  as a team
- If you decide to implement
  AI.

The boards representation in memory will be probably one of the first things you will consider. [This link](http://www.chessbin.com/post/Board-Representation.aspx) presents one way to represent the board and may be useful in general. In most cases it is not so important as to the specific board storage mechanism used as it can be abstracted away.

One way to do AI would be to use the [minimax algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) to look a few moves ahead. You'll benefit here if you kept your worldstate separate to rendering, input etc.

Comment: decided to use gui ..

Comment: we are logically sound. Have done many AI programs but we are not much informed about the user interface and database connectivity thing ...thought about the minimax ... i think modified alfa beta prunning will be better ... there is team of 6, 3 of us are fully dedicated towards the project

Comment: 1 more thing we wanted to make it in 2D only not 3D !!!

Comment: Alpha beta pruning would be much better, and would enable you to do deeper searches. When you say database are you talking about an actual database (e.g. an SQL database?). Why are you considering using a database (you can just keep the game in memory)?.

Comment: saw the board notations as u suggested above. Was thinking about the 2D array implementation. but 1D also wont make much difference.

Comment: Yeah was talking about actual databases.yeah can keep it in memory if that is not possible in 2 months.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Your advise really boosted us :) !!!

Comment: Can someone suggest some C# or java books to refer.

Comment: @Kiran: try www.flazx.com It has books on almost every branch of Computer Science.